# Ordered set notation

Tags: printing, scheme

I'm given the following implementation of an ordered structure at my disposal:

```
;; os-empty         an empty set
;; (os-singleton e) produces a set with one element e
;; (os-member s e)  produces true if e is a member of s; false otherwise
;; (os-union s t)   produces union of s and t in time 
;;                                  O(min(|s|,|t|) log max(|s|,|t|)
;; (os-intersection s t) produces intersection of s and t in time 
;;                                  O(min(|s|,|t|) log max(|s|,|t|)
;; (os-difference s t)   produces difference  s \ t in time 
;;                                  O(min(|s|,|t|) log max(|s|,|t|)
;; (os-min s)       produces the to-min element of s, or to-min-ident
;;                        running time:  O(log |s|)
;; (os-max s)       produces the to-max element of s, or to-max-ident
;;                        running time:  O(log |s|)
;; (os-after s e)   produces the to-min element of s which is to> than e
;;                        running time:  O(log |s|)
;; (os-before s e)  produces the to-max element of s which is to< than e
;;                        running time:  O(log |s|)
;; (os-op)          produces the result of applying to-op over all e in s
;;                        running time:  O(1)
```

The code can be found in the following files: https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs136/assignments/a8/ordered-set.rkt and https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs136/assignments/a8/total-order.rkt

The structure doesn't allow duplicates in it. Here is my problem: I need to write a program that writes each distinct integer in ascending order, followed by a space, followed by the number of times it occurs in the input, to a separate line of output.

```
Sample Input

1
3
2
1
Output for Sample Input

1 2
2 1
3 1
```

Here is what I've got:

```
 ;;Prints in ascending order
    (define (printer e s)  
      (cond
        [(equal? (to-unhide e) +inf.0) (printf "")]
        [else (printf "~a\n" (to-unhide e)) (printer (os-after s e) s)]))


    (define (main) 
     (define x (read))
     (cond
       [(eof-object? x) (printer (os-min o) o)]
       [(os-member o (os-singlton (to-hide x))) ....... <--- What to do?
       [else (set! o (os-union (os-singleton (to-hide x)) o)) (main)]))   


    (main)
```

My problem is how to make a counter based on the x, and how to make that counter special for x... i was thinking about making a function that produces variables but I don't think that is possible for Scheme. Any suggestions how to remember the amount of times an input has been used using this structure ?

Answer (score 1):

Separate your task into smaller chunks.
Here is one way to divide your tasks into smaller functions.

1. Write   list->ordered-set : list-of-numbers -> ordered-set
   That converts a list of numbers in to an ordered set.
2. Write   read-numbers : list-of-strings -> list-of-numbers
   That converts a lists of strings into a list of numbers
3. Write   read-all-lines : -> list-of-strings
   That that repeatedly uses read-line until eof is seen,
   and returns a list of all lines read.
4. Use a printer on (list->ordered-set (read-numbers (read-all-lines))).

Comment: I can't use lists, just the funtions i provided in the beginning of the question..

Comment: Then combine number 1 and 2 into one function. But, erm, you are aware that holding the numbers read in a list won't affect your running time negatively.

Comment: Wont i still be using list's? The structure provided doesn't add duplicates to the structure. So thts why i ahve the line `(os-member o (os-singlton (to-hide x)))` to check if x is already in o and if it is i want to add like a counter only to that x, but i dont know how to do that..

Comment: If a set S contains an element e, then S U {e} = S, therefore you don't need to check whether e already is in S. Simple make a loop what begins with an empty set, then add one number at a time without checking for duplicates.

Comment: I'm still a little lost on your strategy. Say i input the number 4, two times and the number 2, three times .... the second time i input four you want me to create another structure? and what do you mean by "one number" at a time ?

Comment: and don't i need to check for duplicates to produce the second column of the output ?